# SQL query to get records of a timeframe with sequence of events related to the same identifier

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am learning SQL and I stuck on this:

I have this example table with date fomat (dd/mm/yyyy):

| Date | ID | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/09/2022 | xxx | opened |
| 07/07/2022 | xxx | delivered |
| 01/06/2022 | xxx | sent |
| 10/08/2022 | yyy | opened |
| 08/08/2022 | yyy | delivered |
| 01/08/2022 | yyy | sent |

I want to get the records for the last 3 months:

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE  Date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
 
 AND
 
 Date <= DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
```

Which worked fine but my issue that all Status (sent, delivered & opened) should included per ID in the time frame.

So the above query will get me ID `yyy` perfectly but for `xxx` it will break it because the sent status row is on 01/06/2022

I tried to use `group by ID` and having `Status IN ('sent','delivered','opened')`

But it does not work and show all the records!

**Wanted output** is just the same table with records of yyy as one record of xxx status 'sent' is out of the timeframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which worked fine but my issue that all Status (sent, delivered & opened) should included per ID in the time frame.

Adding condition to filter only Ids that have all 3 statuses in the timeframe:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE Date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
  AND Date <= DATEADD(DAY, 0, GETDATE())
QUALIFY COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Status IN ('sent','delivered','opened') 
                       THEN status END) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY Id) = 3
```